# Number of diastereomer pairs of 1,3-dichloro-1,2,3-triphenylpropane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image: 1,1',1''-(1,3-dichloropropane-1,2,3-triyl)tribenzene]

How can I determine the number of possible pairs of diastereomers here?

My first guess was two: RR with RS and SS with RS. But what about the potential chirality center middle carbon? There are two identical branches attached to it; however, those two branches can change R/S. So, is it a chirality center?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I basically agree with Ron's answer, but had to draw all of the possible structures to confirm it. The complication is that carbon-2 is *[non-stereogenic](http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05980.html)* but it may be *[chirotopic](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01065.html)* depending on the configuration of the neighboring atoms. The IUPAC Gold Book calls this a [pseudo-asymmetric carbon atom](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04921.html). Carbon-2 is not a stereocenter, because it does not have four different "things" attached to it. However, its configuration is important relative to carbons-1 and -3. Below are all of the possible combinations.

[image]

Out of the eight possibilities, we see there are only four unique compounds (names generated in ChemDraw):

A: (1​*R*,2​*s*,3​*S*)-1,3-dichloro-1,2,3-triphenylpropane

B: (1​*S*,3​*S*)-1,3-dichloro-1,2,3-triphenylpropane

C: (1​*R*,2​*r*,3​*S*)-1,3-dichloro-1,2,3-triphenylpropane

F: (1​*R*,3​*R*)-1,3-dichloro-1,2,3-triphenylpropane

The small *r* and *s* are essentially used to indicate the stereochemistry at carbon-2 relative to carbons-1 and -3. Note that in compounds B and F, the stereochemistry at carbon-2 is inconsequential as in both cases the phenyl group is syn to one chloride and anti to another chloride. I haven't been able to find an adequate explanation of assigning the *r*/*s* designations, but I believe that the *R* configured substituent receives higher priority than the *S* configured substituent, and Cahn–Ingold–Prelog system is followed from there.

Comment: Hmm. The solutions said the answer was two. Like my guess... I conclude that the solutions is mistaken.

Comment: Carbon 2 is achirotopic, not chirotopic and it is called a stereocenter as it can have r/s configuration. It is not strictly a chiral center because two attached groups differ only by their configurations.

Comment: As far as I can tell (by reading Anslyn/Dougherty section 6.3.3) C-2 is chirotopic only in those isomers which are chiral, i.e. **B** and **F**. In the meso compounds **A** and **C**, C-2 lies within the plane of symmetry and is therefore achirotopic. So, both of you are correct. :)

Comment: As for the r/s notation, future visitors to this question may be interested in: [What does lowercase r-s notation mean?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5597/16683) and [IUPAC name for 1,2,3-trichlorocyclopropane?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35486/16683) where the notation is explained in detail with reference to the Blue Book.

Comment: @orthocresol I've changed it to reflect that C2 may or may not be in a chiral environment.

Comment: CIP-assignments of A and C are incorrect. Actually, they are correct assignments of E and G. I appreciate if you correct them ASAP.

Answer (score 13):

Let's number the 3 aliphatic carbons to make our discussion clearer.

[image]

Using the definition of a chiral carbon as a carbon that has 4 different substituents, carbons 1, 2 and 3 are all capable of being chiral. Carbons 1 and 3 are relatively straightforward chiral carbons, it's easy to see the 4 different substituents and assign "*R*" or "*S*" configurations.  However carbon 2 is problematic.

If we assign *R*- and *S*- configurations to carbons 1 and 3 respectively, then there are 4 different groups attached to carbon 2, but the difference in 2 of the groups is just "*R*" or "*S*".  In fact, in this situation there is actually a plane of symmetry bisecting the molecule and the molecule is achiral - it is a *meso*-isomer.  The plane of symmetry contains carbon 2 and the hydrogen and phenyl group attached to carbon 2, and, as expected, the *R*- and *S*-substituents are enantiomeric.  In such cases it is correct to say that carbon 2 is [*pseudo*-asymmetric](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/P/P04921.html) (thanks to @GaurangTandon for pointing this out!). The Cahn–Ingold–Prelog priority rules can still be used to describe carbon 2, the *R* substituent is given priority over the *S* substituent and lowercase "*r*" and "*s*" are used to describe carbon 2, the *pseudo*-asymmetric carbon.

In the case where we assign *R*- and *R*- (or *S*- and *S*-) configurations to carbons 1 and 3 respectively, then there is no longer a plane of symmetry bisecting the molecule.  Carbon 2 is now [prochiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prochirality) (this means changing one substituent is all that is required to make carbon 2 chiral), but the molecule as a whole is now chiral.

Going in the order carbon 1-2-3 here are the various possibilities:

1. 1*R*,3*R* is chiral and it has an enantiomer 1*S*,3*S*
2. 1*R*,2*r*,3*S* is an achiral (there is a plane of symmetry bisecting the molecule), *meso*-compound and a diastereomer of 1*R*,3*R*;
3. 1*R*,2*s*,3*S* is a second achiral, *meso*-compound.

So there are 3 diastereomers; one is chiral and exists as a *d,l* pair and the two other  diastereomers are achiral, *meso*-compounds.

Comment: Ron, just to be sure, the question was asking for pairs.
So, I'm listing them:

1. 1R,3R and 1R,2r,3S

2. 1R,3R and 1R,2s,3S

3. 1S,3S and 1R,2r,3S

4. 1S,3S and 1R,2s,3S

5. 1R,2s,3S and 1R,2r,3S

Could you please back me up? I found 5 total.

Comment: This is actually quite weird. This was a multiple choice question and there not odd numbers :O ! I should use another exercise package. Too many mistakes.

Comment: @yolo123  I don't think that is right.  Diastereomers don't come in "pairs".  As I said in my answer, there are 3 diastereomers.  Maybe the question was asking how many pairs of enantiomers?

Comment: Oh boy! Why have I not thought of that...? Word for word:
"How many pairs of diastereomers are possible in the following molecule? PhCH(Cl)CH(Ph)CH(Cl)Ph?"

Comment: Definitely, this question is very ambiguous... Honestly, thanks a lot jerepierre and ron. Very informative.

Comment: Unless I misdrew the molecule from the condensed structural formula.... But I don't think so...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is hindered enough to prevent rotation around the central carbon, so I think it only has two stereogenic centres, leading to four possible stereocentre combinations as you have identified: RR, SS, SR, RS

This results in more than two pairs of diastereomers though:

1) RR with SR
2) RR with RS
3) SS with SR
4) SS with RS

Comment: This analysis is incomplete because there are two possible compounds with configuration (1R,3S), depending on the relative (syn/anti) configuration at C-2.

Comment: @jerepierre Indeed, thanks for posting a better one :)