# How many stereogenic centers exist in the atropine?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

[image]

I'm pretty sure that both C bonded to N are stereogenic centers. I don't know about the others, any help? Is this correct?
[image]

Comment: I think there is only one chiral center in atropine.

Comment: @Curt F.: The ring is symmetric so all three carbon centers shown in are not chiral. The sole chiral center is the $\alpha$-carbon to carbonyl group.

Comment: Hi, actually I meant stereogenic center, I don't know if it's different from the definition of chiral center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/153711/97580) you can look at the IUPAC definition of the chiral center. According to the definition, carbons that are attached to nitrogen are chiral centers — they have 4 different chemical groups attached to them. The $\alpha$-carbon to the ester group is also a chiral center. However, the third carbon (from top to bottom) that you circled is not a chiral center because two groups from the cycle are identical.

Comment: Yes, nevertheless, the "third carbon" is a pseudoasymmetric center (_r_ or _s_).

Comment: IUPAC defines chirality centre (https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.C01060) as *An atom holding a set of ligands in a spatial arrangement which is not superposable on its mirror image.* That doesn't necessarily mean that it has to be four different groups, although that is a convenient rule of thumb.

Comment: @Loong you're right but question asks for **chiral** centers

Comment: @Martin-マーチン in definition that you referred to it's written *Cabcd*. And it's also written that this is a generalization of concept of asymmetric carbon atom which is defined as I wrote (https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.A00479). If I am wrong somewhere, please correct me.

Comment: Hi, actually I meant stereogenic center, I don't know if it's different from the definition of chiral center.

Comment: Well, the second part is in principle an example, where it generalizes the concept of Cabcd to other species. It is not necessary for the definition.

Answer (score 11):

I assume the OP means atropine in which case the structure presented has an extra methylene group. The renderings of a single enantiomer of atropine by ChemDraw 20.1 and JSmol are shown below. 
Using the terminology of [Mislow and Siegel](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00323a043), the bridgehead carbons and the benzylic carbon are stereogenic and chirotopic, Thus, the R/S designation. The remaining carbon labeled "r" is stereogenic but achirotopic (r/s). Therefore, there are four stereogenic centers three of which are chirotopic.

[image]
[image]