# is this compound meso? trans-1,4 dimethylcyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, symmetry

I had a question on a quiz that asked if the compound below was meso or not. I thought that it would be meso because there is a plane of symmetry going through the two methyls, but the answer was that it is not meso. I'm pretty sure that plane of symmetry is allowed to go through atoms, so I was wondering why it wasn't meso.

[image: trans-1,4 dimethylcyclohexane]

*If the picture isn't showing up, it is a trans-1,4 dimethylcyclohexane

Comment: What is a meso, come to think of it?

Comment: In meso compounds plane goes *between* atoms, otherwise you have identical substituents - no chiral center!

Comment: A meso compound must have an associated d,l pair, like the three tartaric acids.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on a past post here:[Does 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane have a chiral center?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153711/does-1-4-dimethylcyclohexane-have-a-chiral-center)

seems that it is not a meso compound because it does not have a chiral center.

Comment: Minus one because you should have commented with the link or reported the duplicate.