# How to determine the configuration of C atom bounded to two groups with same configuration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

What is the configuration of the central C atom in the following molecule and how to determine it?

[image]

Comment: What configuration? There is none. You have two identical substituents.

Comment: But there is no mirror plane passing through the center of the molecule?

Comment: See [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-possible-pairs-of-diastereomers/19099#19099)

Comment: No mirror plane, so what? Can you build another molecule that would have similar side arms (both R), but be different from this one in the central atom's stereo configuration _alone_?

Comment: I see. It is chirotopic.