# Stereocenter or not?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

Consider 2,3,4-pentanetriol.Is the middle carbon atom a stereocentre?I know how to count the stereoisomers, but is the middle carbon a stereocentre by definition?Let us say we have a 2R and 4S configuration.Now if we change the orientation of the OH group at the 3rd carbon, we do get a different compound,but both the compounds are optically inactive, so it doesn't seem it should be called a stereocentre.If we consider 2R,4R, or 2S,4S if we change the configuration at C3, we get the same compoound.So I feel the carbon at C3 should not be a stereocentre.But it seems that in the first case, we are changing the C3 configuration and getting a new diastereoisomer, so C3 might be a stereocentre after all.Which one is correct?If C3 is a stereocentre, what would be its R,S nomenclature?

Comment: [This earlier answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/number-of-diastereomer-pairs-of-1-3-dichloro-1-2-3-triphenylpropane/19099#19099) deals with a similar situation and should prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The carbon atom in question is called pseudo-asymmetric. Check it out on the [IUPAC page](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/P/P04921.html).