# Number of stereoisomers of pentane‐2,3,4‐triol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, alcohols, isomers

> What will be the number of stereoisomers of $\ce{CH3CH(OH)CH(OH)CH(OH)CH3}?$

By formula $2^n - 1 + 2^n + 1/2$ for $n$ being the odd number of chiral centres, it's $6;$ four optically active and two optically inactive.

Optically active  when *RRS*, *SSR*, *RR*, *SS*, but I am not getting how we get two optically inactive.

Comment: Also, [this](http://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/P04921) resource and [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139094/pseudo-chiral-centre) may help you out.

Comment: The remaining two are optically inactive because each of them is a mirror image of itself; what's unclear about that?

Comment: What will be their RS configuration and IUPAC name..?

Comment: What will be iupac name of the achiral stereoisomers..?

Comment: If you read the Answers in my link, the answers will be there.

Comment: So, can we say that it is optically inactive when C1-R,C2-R and C1-S,C2-S?

Comment: Same question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80461/number-of-stereoisomers-and-symmetry-of-pentane-2-3-4-triol#:~:text=The%20above%20drawn%20structures%20are,%2C3%2C4%2Ctriol.)

Comment: Wrap this one up!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of stereoisomers and symmetry of pentane-2,3,4-triol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80461/number-of-stereoisomers-and-symmetry-of-pentane-2-3-4-triol)

Comment: Just ,the question left unanswered is that what will be iupac name of two stereoisomers in which middle carbon is achiral..

Comment: Rover: Read the first example here. http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/RSrs.html